70s serial about French jet fighter pilots
All that I recall was that it was dubbed into English,similar to a serial entitled the flashing blade. It was shown during sat morning kids t.v on either the BBC or ITV. It also may have been set during ww2.
 This was a live action serial in colour made in the late 60s early 70s.

probably a long shot could it be this ? Its the same series you said but its spoofed and telecast for kids, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On_the_Waterfront_(TV_Series)

got the reference to that from here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Flashing_Blade

@Morpheus thanks but the flashing blade was spoofed in the early 80s as per the link.The original was shown in the early/mid  70s and i think the airmen series was around the same time.

I found the answer, I looked at the production company who made the flashing blade. They also produced a serial about jet fighter pilots, the title was "The Aeronauts". The original French title was "Les chevaliers du ciel" (The knights of the sky). 
